# Name of the functional $p \mapsto P_X[p] = X\int_X^\infty p(x)\,dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, expected-value, economics, applications

Let $p(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+_0$ be a probability distribution with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\,dx = 1$. Is there a special name for the parametrized functional

$$p \mapsto P_X[p] = X\int_X^\infty p(x)\,dx\ ?$$

The name of $p \mapsto I_X[p] = \int_X^\infty p(x)\,dx$ is just the **definite integral of $p$ from $X$ to infinity** and $p \mapsto Id_X[p] = X$ possibly doesn't have a name due to its triviality. But what about the product $X\int_X^\infty p(x)\,dx$?

Whether there is a special name or not: Which use cases are there for this functional, e.g. in physics, economics, or statistics? I came across it when I tried to calculate the **expected revenue** when selling a whole stock of products for a given **price $X$** per item with $p(x)$ the **distribution of [willingness to pay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willingness_to_pay)**.

Note the difference with the **expected value**

$$p \mapsto \mathbb{E}[p] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\ p(x)\,dx,$$

which is just another functional.

---

To show what the functional may be good for, I plotted it (blue) for a number of distributions $p(x)$ of willingness to pay (green). The maximum is at the price $X$ for which a maximal revenue can be expected. Depicted in red is the reservation price of the supplier ([willingness to accept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willingness_to_accept), set to $1$).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, just too big for a comment.

Let me put this functional in a simpler form: $P_x(\mu) = x\cdot(1 - F_\mu(x))$ where $F_\mu$ is the CDF for a probability distribution $\mu$. I have not seen this functional being used with a particular name anywhere, but I definitely expect this to be met in economics-like disciplines due to a hard cut and saturation of value at $x$. That looks extremely artificial to me, though by no means I'm an expert say in physics. Regarding economics, I would expect this to be used in at least two cases

1. Options pricing. In digital-like options $P_x(\mu)$ would be a price of an option with a strike $x$ if the underlying distribution at expiry is $\mu$.
2. Mechanism design/auction theory. There it is important to consider both the probability that one gets the lot, and the value of its lot to the winner.
3. *(added with an edit)* Ok, after you've edited I've immediately recalled that it is also used in the proof of [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality), hence likely be used in probability bounds estimations. For example, in the [ruin theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruin_theory) - another area combining economics and probability - once often aims at deriving upper bounds on the ruin probability for a high value of the initial capital. Some of those relate to the aforementioned estimation, hence likely using your operator. Perhaps, my answer just describes at least three uses of the H-PS operator.